# jquery: fade in divs one by one but only have 2 divs visible at a time?

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code to fade in my divs one by one.

```
<script>        
$(document).ready(function(){
    var animations = [];

    $('.noti_box').each(function(i) {
        animations.push(
           $(this).hide().delay(i * 1000).fadeIn(1500).promise()
        );
    });

    $.when.apply($, animations).done(function () {
        time=setInterval(function(){
        if ( $('.noti_box:visible').length === 0 ) {
            $(".advert").fadeIn("slow");
        } },200);
    });
});
</script>
```

A user can click on the div to close it, which will cause that target div to be hidden. I want to improve the above code so that it will fade in my div one by one as it is already doing but also only fade in a maximum of 2 divs at a time. and only fade in more when the user closes a div?

Comment: Could you place all your code (HTML, CSS and JS) in a working fiddle and have a link to it in your question please?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2efwkxn8/

Comment: So you want them to fade in 2 by 2 instead of 1 by 1? Plus, I didn't understand the second part of the question. You say you want more of them to fade in when the user closes a div, but No divs fade in when I close any of them.

Comment: @lucasnadalutti no I have about 20 of these divs and i want them to fade in one by one, but only ever show 2 at any given time

Comment: hmmm .. not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve but maybe just drop the fade in loop at the start, "manually" fade in the first two divs on the page and just use the onclick() of the div boxclose to kill the current div and fade in the next one...